# Is it thread-safe to iterate over an immutable copy of Dictionary values if this copy was made under a lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, readerwriterlockslim

Is the below code thread-safe?

I need to call an `async` method on every `service`, therefore I [cannot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) keep the `foreach` loop under the lock.

But would it be thread-safe to copy all the values from the `_dictionary` to an `ImmutableList` under the lock, exit the lock and then iterate over them as usual and call the `async` method?

```
public class Cache
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim lockObject = new();

    private readonly IDictionary<string, Service> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Service>();

    public Service GetOrAdd(string key)
    {
        lockObject.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var service))
            {
                return service;
            }
            lockObject.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                var value = new Service();
                _dictionary.Add(key, value);
                return service;
            }
            finally
            {
                lockObject.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lockObject.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }

    public async Task CallServices()
    {
        var services = GetServices();
        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            await service.DoStuffAsync();
        }
    }

    private ImmutableList<Service> GetServices()
    {
        lockObject.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dictionary.Values.ToImmutableList();
        }
        finally
        {
            lockObject.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing the `Dictionary` with the `ConcurrentDictionary` and removing the lock from the `GetServices` is one option, but I still have to keep the lock in `GetOrAdd` because in realilty I have 2 collections to maintain, not only the `_dictionary`. I was wondering if it was possible to use a normal `Dictionary`.

Comment: So you basically want to ensure only 1 item is added to dictionary when it's not there?

Comment: @TomasChabada, yes. If the item with this key is already in the dictionary, I want to return the existing one. If it is not, then I want to create a new one. Like a cache.

Comment: Have you considered using `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, I have noted in the question that `ConcurrentDictionary` is an option. However, since I still need to keep the lock, I was hoping to replace the `ConcurrentDictionary` with the normal `Dictionary`, otherwise it may look confusing why I need both the `ConcurrentDictionary` and the lock.

Comment: And why do you need lock with concurrent dictionary?

Comment: @GuruStron, because in the real code I have another collection that I need to update when I update the `ConcurrentDictionary`. And I need these two updates to be atomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, yes.

Since the copy of the dictionary is made while the lock is held there should be no risk that the dictionary is read and written to concurrently. And [concurrent reads are safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0):

> A Dictionary<TKey,TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified

The created copy is a local variable, and cannot be accessed by multiple threads, so using this is thread safe by default. There is not even any need to make it immutable, using a regular list would work just as well.

But this is specifically for the accessing the dictionary. `.DoStuffAsync()` could still be unsafe, but I assume that is out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, ensuring that `DoStuffAsync()` is thread-safe is a separate task. If I am removing `.ToImmutableList()`, is it possible for the content of the list to change during iteration over it if another thread, say, concurrently adds something the dictionary?

Comment: @yaskovdev No. Changes to the dictionary cannot affect copies that have already been created. How would that work? But both collections will still refer to the same *objects*, and these can still change.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not thread-safe. Just because the *collection* is immutable does not mean that the data *IN* the collection is immutable, and you do not have any locking to protect the individual records.

Consider the following modified cache code:

```
public class Cache
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim lockObject = new();

    private readonly IDictionary<string, Service> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Service>();

    public Service GetOrAdd(string key)
    {
        lockObject.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var service))
            {
                return service;
            }
            lockObject.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                var value = new Service();
                _dictionary.Add(key, value);
                return service;
            }
            finally
            {
                lockObject.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lockObject.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }

    public async Task CallServices()
    {
        var services = GetServices();
        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            await service.DoStuffAsync();
        }
    }

    private ImmutableList<Service> GetServices()
    {
        lockObject.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return _dictionary.Values.ToImmutableList();
        }
        finally
        {
            lockObject.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    
    public void VerifyServices(int expectedCount)
    {
        var services = GetServices();
        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            if (service.Count != expectedCount)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Expected count: {expectedCount}. Actual count: {service.Count}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where Service modifies itself in `DoStuffAsync`:

```
public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
    public int Count { get; set; } = 1;
    
    public async Task DoStuffAsync()
    {
        Count++;
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

If we test it with the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var cache = new Cache();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var key = i.ToString();
        cache.GetOrAdd(key);
    }
    
    var taskCount = 100;
    var tasks = new Task[taskCount];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => cache.CallServices());
    }
    
    Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
    cache.VerifyServices(taskCount);
}
```

an exception will be thrown during VerifyServices because the updates to the `Service` objects were done outside of the scope of a lock, even though the collection itself is immutable.

In conclusion, while the *collection* is immutable, there is nothing that guarantees that the contents themselves are safe from mutation. You'll have to determine if that caveat is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if I am sure that `Service` does not contain any mutable state, can I read the `_dictionary.Values` under the lock to the local variable and then iterate over them safely? Making sure that `Service` is thread-safe is another topic. :)

Comment: @yaskovdev thank you for clarifying. As is, what you have should be thread-safe, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the below code thread-safe?

So it depends what thread safety you are talking about - from dictionary standpoint of view it would be thread safe (actually I would argue that it is quite similar to want [`ConcurrentDictionary.Values` does](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Concurrent/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2158)).

But from items returned by the collection it would not be thread safe and working with them will require extra synchronization (if needed).

Comment: Got it, thank you for the answer. For now I assume that the items do not contain any mutable state, i.e., I only care about thread-safety from the dictionary standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking basically is whether enumerating an [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1) is thread-safe. You are not concerned about the thread-safety of the `T`, but only about the thread-safety of enumerating the immutable collection. The answer is: it's perfectly safe. The immutable collections are thread-safe by design. Actually it is [explicitly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1#thread-safety) that the `ImmutableList<T>` collection is thread-safe:

> This type is thread safe.

There are no exceptions. No ifs or whens. A thread can do whatever it wants with an `ImmutableList<T>`, and no other thread will ever be affected.

It should be noted that your `GetServices` method creates a new copy of the values of the `_dictionary` each time it is called, so the lists created by your code are not shared between threads, and so you wouldn't have any problems even if the `ImmutableList<T>` class was not thread-safe. I am pretty sure that if you change your code from `return _dictionary.Values.ToImmutableList();` to `return _dictionary.Values.ToList();`, the correctness of your application will not be compromised to the slightest.

Comment: Very well explained. Special thanks for the remark regarding changing `.ToImmutableList()` to `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get the item from dictionary (`dictionary.TryGetValue`...) can be put outside of lock statement. 
Lock only when item is not found and then, inside the lock ask again if it's not there, since many threads might find the first condition (`dictionary.TryGetValue`...) as false, and only if it's still `false` perform the insert.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Althought I have not expilicitly stated this in the question, in my case the vast majority of the requests are reads with only a few writes, so I am not sure if introducing a new check outside of the lock will be a noticeable performance improvement.